# change contents of a table by taking data from another table in react

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react and I am trying to  make a simple task management app.

```js
function isWorkDayNov(date, month = 10, year = 2020) {
  const weekDay = new Date(year, month, date).getDay()
  return  weekDay !== 0 && weekDay !== 6; 
}

function DateCellNov({date}) {
  return <td className={isWorkDayNov(date) ? 'workday' : 'weekend'}>{date}</td>
}
function isTask1(date, month = 10, year = 2020) {
  const task1WorkDay = new Date(year, month, date).getDay();
  console.log(task1WorkDay);
  return task1WorkDay !== 0 && task1WorkDay !== 6;
}

function DateCellTask1({ date }) {
  return (<td className={isTask1(date) ? "workday" : "weekend"}>task</td>);
}


class HomePage extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      task: {
        task1: {
          date: "17"
        }
      }
    }
  }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th colSpan="7">Nov</th></tr>
                    <tr><th colSpan="7">Week 1</th></tr>
                    <tr>{[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22].map(date => <DateCellNov key={date} date={date} />)}</tr>
                    <tr>{[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22].map(date => <DateCellTask1 key={date} date={this.state.task.task1.date} />)}</tr>
                 </tbody>
                </table>
                <br></br>
                <div>
                  <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr><th colSpan="4">Table 2</th></tr>
                        <tr><th>Task</th><th>Time</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>Task 1</td><td>16 Hrs</td><td>17-Nov-2020</td><td>18-Nov-2020</td></tr>
                     </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<HomePage />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.weekend {
  background-color: pink;
}
.workday {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

At `console.log(task1WorkDay);` in `function isTask1` you can see that I am getting value 2 in the console, but instead of populating whole row with `task`, I just want to populate the cell under 17 and 18 Nov, because task1 is to be performed on those days only. I can't figure out what changes should I make in code to do this? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

try to do some sort of `conditions` to display `task` only on day `17 & 18`:-

- maybe create a `state` that hold `start` & `end` date of `task` (Eg: `taskDates = [17, 18]`):-

```js
function DateCellTask1({ date }) {
  return (
    <td className={isTask1(date) ? "workday" : "weekend"}>
      {date.includes(taskDates) ? 'task' : 'none'}
    </td>
  );
}
```